# google docs api documents.get multiple fields ? (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-docs-api

How can I select multiple fields when using the [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22ID%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22body%2Fcontent%2Ftable%2FtableRows%2FstartIndex%22%7D) ?

Right now I am getting the documenmt like this:

```
  const doc = await docs.documents.get({
    documentId: copiedFile.data.id,
    fields: 'body/content'
  });
```

which returns this:

```
"data": {
  "body": {
    "content": [...]
  }
}
```

However, I need to also get the `inlineObject` and the only way so far I have been able to do so, is by removing the `fields` proeprty completely

```
  const doc = await docs.documents.get({
    documentId: copiedFile.data.id,
  });
```

Then I get this:

```
"data": {
  "title": "Some document title",
  "body": {
    "content": [...]
  },
  "headers": {
  },
  "footers": {
  },
  "documentStyle": {
  },
  "namedStyles": {
  },
  "lists": {
  },
  "revisionId": "some-long-id",
  "suggestionsViewMode": "SUGGESTIONS_INLINE",
  "inlineObjects": {
  },
  "documentId": "some-long-id"
}
```

But I am really only interested in `data.body.content` and `data.inlineObjects`
When selecting everything the response is many thousands of lines of json larger, which I don't want.

I have tried `fields: ['body/content', 'inlineObjects']` but that only returns `body.content` and not the `inlineObjects` - also the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22ID%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22body%2Fcontent%2Ftable%2FtableRows%2FstartIndex%22%7D) doesn't mention this syntax anywhere, it was just to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't return any `inlineObjects` when you don't have any `inlineObjects` in the document. To confirm if the actual format is working and the statement above is true, try using other fields where a value is confirmed to be returned such as `revisionId` or `title`.

#### Test:

```
const doc = await docs.documents.get({
  documentId: copiedFile.data.id,
  fields: 'body/content,inlineObjects'
});
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Great, thanks for the inspiration! So the syntax is: `fields: 'body/content,inlineObjects'` in one string - (this is a little unusual when working in JavaScript). I tested it and it works exactly how I needed it to.